# Access the user's location on Today Extension

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, ios8, ios-app-extension

Is it possible to access the user's location on a widget?

I used the new iOS 8 API

```
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

and I added to the info.plist file the key

```
NSLocationWhenInUseDescription
```

however, when I request the location access, an alert should appear, but it doesn't happen.

Are there some not declared limitations on iOS today extensions?

Comment: I also tried to obtain permissions from the containing app, but on the widget I still have the same issue

Comment: [This little demo](https://github.com/HeEAaD/LocationWidget) worked fine on iOS 8 beta 1, maybe it's useful to you (I am not the author).

Answer (score 4):

As I found out, `didUpdateLocations:` delegate method doesn't work in today extension. So, to get location use `locationManager.location`.

Answer (score 1):

Along with requesting authorization, you must also explicitly ask your location manager to start updating locations.

```
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Answer (score 1):

The key `NSLocationWhenInUseDescription` is wrong, therefore the Alert doesn't come up.

Change it to `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and it should work.

For all keys you can refer to this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Answer (score 0):

The authorization dialog does not pop up in extensions. Your app, which should be in the same App Group (in capabilities)